# Convergence/Divergence Test for $1 - 1/2^3 +1/3 -1/4^3 +.....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm looking back in a math textbook in a chapter about series and convergence of series

I'm stuck trying to determine the convergence of $1-1/2^3+1/3-1/4^3+1/5 -....$ which is essentially the sum of terms $\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{2+(-1)^k}}$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$

The hint that I got was that the Leibniz Criterion and the direct comparison test to find a convergent series are not helpful here, so instead I should look for a smaller divergent series to compare it to. The problem is none come to mind. There also aren't very many series I can look back on in this chapter. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The idea here is that even and odd terms are much different, so it is much better to consider them separately!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That series diverges, since the series$$1+0+\frac13+0+\frac15+0+\cdots$$diverges, the series$$0-\frac1{2^3}+0-\frac1{4^3}+0-\frac1{6^3}+\cdots$$converges, and since your series is the term-by-term sum of these two series.